# Zero by zero division and complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, polar-coordinates, angle

To my knowledge, zero divided by zero is neither zero, nor infinity, it can't be understood.
Let a complex function of a real variable $w$ be
$$
Z(w) = iw = 0 + iw
$$
Now, generally the argument of this variable is $ \arctan (\frac{w}{0})  = 90^\circ $. Now, if $Z(w)$ is a transfer function and I'm measuring the frequency response phase angle at $w = 0$, How is $\angle Z = 90^\circ$, given that at $w=0$ the argument becomes $\arctan(\frac{0}{0})$ ?

Comment: $\arctan (\frac{w}{0})  = 90^\circ$ is wrong because $\frac w 0$ is undefined. And the complex number $z=0 + i0$ does not have an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a division to define an argument, as it would be generally better to use the [double argument arctangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

This way: $\angle Z =\arctan2(w,0) = 90^\circ$ if $w>0$.

If $w=0$ as well, then the argument of the complex number is undefined, but you might just use a convention to say it is zero or other convenient value for some special application, since it also has no radius, it should hardly matter,

Comment: O yes! I see, I was thinking about the frequency response of a pole at origin, frequency response doesn't care about w=0, so as a convention we take it as 90 degrees, it doesn't matter like you said.